# Why does cuckoo hashing use mod 11 for two tables

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable

I am learning about hashing today, but I don't understand why some example using "mod table_length" and why a lot of examples use "mod 11" for two tables

Comment: I don't know for sure, but don't think that 11 has any special relation to cuckoo hashing. Mod-values are usually prime numbers and 11 is simply a low prime number that's easy to calculate in examples.

Comment: Can see mod 11 often at https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/roche/courses/240/module05.pdf - as Joachim says it's a good choice as a low prime, with enough buckets to fit on a slide at readable font size, whilst illustrating some interesting collision handling behaviours.  Nothing magical about it for real-world data.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is “cuckoo hashing doesn’t use mod 11.” Cuckoo hashing assumes you have two hash functions that give positions across two tables, and it’s common to take hash functions modulo the table size so that items are mapped to a slot index in a table. However, I’ve never seen 11 specifically used for cuckoo hashing - perhaps it’s an artifact of a slide deck where someone needed a hash function for a table that conveniently fits onto a single slide?

Comment: Concur, this is a slide consideration, not a technical one.